# How to show laravel group by collection data in vue.js frond-end

Tags: laravel, vue.js, collections, frontend, vue-component

here is my collection data
[image]

How to show this collection data in Vue file.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) package at the Vue side (at the frontend).
2. Then send an API request using Axios from Vue component to backend, and this API should return the response you have mentioned.
3. Now, use this response in the Vue component.
4. See this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-platform-xjfeu?file=/src/App.vue)